# Vue JS casing issue when displaying object, output does not match what I'm seeing in dev tools when it come to casing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

## Problem:

Object I'm trying to display does not match what is rendered on the web page. For some reason when I display an object in data it renders it with some casing rules applied to it.

## Vue Dev Tools View Of Object

[image: What I'm seeing in dev tools]

## Output rendered on web page

[[image: What I'm seeing displayed][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tE3C.png)

## Code

```
<template>
   <v-card>
       <v-card-text>
            {{testObject}}
       </v-card-text>
   </v-card>
</template>
```

## Things I've tried

```
<template>

<template>
   <v-card>
       <v-card-text>
            {{JSON.stringify(testObject})}
       </v-card-text>
   </v-card>
</template>
</template>
```

I'm using Typescript Vue and have vuetify

They both ended up rendering the same thing.

When I console.log it shows the correct string so why is it rendering it this way?

Comment: Output from what?

Comment: Specifically, the text that's being rendered on the web page

Comment: Please show the code is what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was v-card-tex rules that was applying standard grammar rules. If you're using a code editor component or displaying code it will throw it off if it resides in v-card-text